# What font is used in Google Play Books in the navigation drawer?

Tags: android

I am sure that the font is Roboto, but I'm trying to replicate it, and I'm having trouble. Any is this just Roboto or Roboto Thin?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about font identification. Try http://whatthefont.com.

Comment: Roboto. It's on the dev guide.

Comment: I know it's roboto (I mention that right in the first line), but I'm not sure if it's thin/light/regular.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google play apps seems to be Roboto Thin in the navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Its **Roboto**. Sample and font available [**here**](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto).